# always getting one value undefined when parsing a json string and json.stringify not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, frontend

I'm building a website in node js express with ejs view.

I'm taking some data from an array and saving it to session storage.
 then I stringify it and catch it on a function call connected to an HTML card click.
 but whenever I stringify the parsed data and passed it to the data of ajax.
 The API call is not happening giving an undefined error.

Here is my code:

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
console.log(parsedData, 'parsedData');
var d = JSON.stringify(parsedData);
console.log(d, 'd');

const container = document.getElementById('s1');

parsedData.data.rows.forEach((result, idx) => {
  var pid = result.master_id;
  var session = result.session_name;
  console.log(pid, session, 'a', 'b');
  var c = { pid, session };
  console.log(c, 'csdc');
  var userData = c;

  sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userData));
  console.log(userData, 'data for api');

  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList = 'card';

  const content = `
          <div class="row">
             <div class="card" id="${result.master_id}" onclick="approve(this.id)" >
          
             
              <div class="card-body" id="${c}" onclick="graphApi(this.id)">
                <br>`
                ...
});
```

in my ejs. using this id="${c}"  onclick i call this function,

```
function graphApi(id) {
  var json = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
  console.log(json, 'value from card');

  var data = JSON.stringify(json);

  console.log(data1, 'data1 here');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,

    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/graphFromcsvfile',
    success: function (data) {
      alert('success');
      console.log(data, 'graph api');
    },
    error: function (err) {
      alert('graph api failed to load');
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
}
```

I'm getting an ajax error in the browser saying,

```
responseJSON: {
  message: 'Error: WHERE parameter "pid" has invalid "undefined" value';
}
responseText: '{"message":"Error: WHERE parameter \\"pid\\" has invalid \\"undefined\\" value"}';
```

Regards.

Comment: looks like server complains about missing parameters. so... whats the content of your json?

Comment: {
    "pid":"WEB506",
    "session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S2.csv"
}        actually this the content i'm passing to req.body. its a post request. if i add this as  the data to ajax . it will work i tested. but i need to get the data from that storage.

Comment: {pid: 'WEB506', session: 'WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv'} 'csdc'   and i'm getting this as my value from var c. i thing this is not json key value pair. is trhat why its giving undefined?

Comment: why are you parsing it from JSON to an object, back to JSON? Why are you not just sending up the localstorage value?

Comment: So what is exactly written in the local storage?  `console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));`

Comment: its the json string with two key value pair